# Merging "fourier-series" and "trigonometric-series"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging, tag-management, retagging

Currently, [fourier-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fourier-series) has 2202 questions and 101 followers, while [trigonometric-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometric-series) has only 324 questions and 9 followers. I suggest merging the two, but also keeping "trigonometric-series" as a tag synonym of "fourier-series".

Comment: I do not think this is a good idea; these are different topics. Both tags serve different purposes, and I would prefer keeping them separate. The theory of trigonometric series is a (very) classical topic, and as such not so active nowadays, which explains the smaller number of questions. (Personally, I am interested in some research problems that definitely belong to this area, and for which the techniques of Fourier series seem irrelevant.)

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo: The [current description](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/fourier-series/info) of "fourier-series" says: *"Questions on Fourier series, the expansion of a function in terms of basis functions that satisfy an orthogonality relation. Usually, complex exponentials or sines and cosines are used."* To me, this is not significantly different from the [current description](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/trigonometric-series/info) of "trigonometric-series" (notice that Fourier series explicitly mention sines and cosines as a possible basis).

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo: For abstract Fourier analysis there is the tag ["harmonic-analysis"](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/harmonic-analysis/info).